# How to delay, offset Pulsator4Droid animation in android?

Tags: android, github, android-animation

I am using [Pulsator4Droid](https://github.com/booncol/Pulsator4Droid) library for putting multiple pulsators on a single layout. Everything works fine but I need to modify it.
The problem is I want them to execute one after the other. Stopping one and then executing the next.
But I don't know which property I should manipulate to achieve this. How do I delay or offset their time?

**LAYOUT FILE:**

```
<pl.bclogic.pulsator4droid.library.PulsatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/pulsator_1"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="144dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="176dp"
    app:pulse_count="5"
    app:pulse_duration="3000"
    app:pulse_repeat="0"
    app:pulse_color="#FF8F00"
    app:pulse_startFromScratch="false"
    app:pulse_interpolator="Decelerate">
</pl.bclogic.pulsator4droid.library.PulsatorLayout>

<pl.bclogic.pulsator4droid.library.PulsatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/pulsator_2"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="232dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    app:pulse_count="5"
    app:pulse_duration="3000"
    app:pulse_repeat="0"
    app:pulse_color="#FF8F00"
    app:pulse_startFromScratch="false"
    app:pulse_interpolator="Decelerate">
</pl.bclogic.pulsator4droid.library.PulsatorLayout>
```

If anyone knows the answer. Please help:(